# For loops function

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, break

The program reads five characters (one for each iteration of the for loop) from the keyboard. Note that getchar()
gets a single character from the keyboard, and putchar() writes a single character (in this case, ch) to the console
screen.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You don't appear to have described a problem or asked a question.  So at this time there's nothing we can do to help you.  To learn about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide the code you are discussing